# Hacer cambiar un select a partir de otro bloquearlo y hacer cambiar otro select dependiente del segundo

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Este es el código que contiene el `select` principal
en este caso es un `select` que se llama estado laboral para guardar el estado laboral del usuario.

```
<label for="" style="position:absolute;top:20.4rem;left:1.6rem;">Estado laboral </label>
                    <select name="elaboral" id="estadolaboral" class="select-css" style="width:190px;">
                        <?php 
                        $con = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * from etrabajo");
                        while($di = mysqli_fetch_array($con)){
                     
                        
                        ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $di[0]?>"><?php echo $di[1]?></option>
                        <?php  } ?>
                    </select>
```

Luego lo que tiene que pasar es que si el usuario selecciona la opción uno que es empleado; entonces que autoseeleccione en el select regimen la opción 2 y que bloquee para que el usuario no pueda seleccionar la otra opción que es subsidiado, pero si el usuario selecciona la primera opción entonces que no pase nada y que el usuario pueda seleccionar cualquiera de los demás regimenes, si he podido lograrlo pero entonces no me autoselecciona las eps que pertenecen al regimen contributivo creo que es por el `onchange` ya que las eps dependen del regimen

```
<label for="" style="position:absolute;top:20.3rem; left:13.8rem;">Regimen</label>

                    <select name="regimen" id="regimeneditar" class="select-css" style="width:190px;">
                        <?php 
                               $con = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * from regimen");
                         while($di = mysqli_fetch_array($con)){
 
    
                    ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $di[0]?>"><?php echo $di[1]?></option>
                        <?php  } ?>
                    </select>
```

La eps la muestro de esta manera la cual depende del regimen el problema es que logro que el primero cambie el segundo es decir que el estado laboral ponga en contribo el regimen si la opcion es 1 pero entonces no me aparecen las eps por que es una funcion onchange entonces ¿Que podria hacer?

```
<label for="" style="position:absolute;top:20.3rem; left:26rem;">Eps</label>
                    <select name="eps" id="epseditar" class="select-css" style="width:190px;">
                        <?php 
                        $con = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * from eps");
                        while($di = mysqli_fetch_array($con)){
                     
                        
                        ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $di[0]?>"><?php echo $di[1]?></option>
                        <?php  } ?>
                    </select>
                    
                    <script>
                    $(document).ready(function() {
                        var eps = $('#epseditar');
                        $('#regimeneditar').change(function() {
                            var regimen = $(this).val();
                            $.ajax({
                                data: {
                                    regimen: regimen
                                },
                                dataType: 'html',
                                type: 'POST',
                                url: '../../geteps.php',
                            }).done(function(data) {
                                eps.html(data);
                            });
                        });
                    });
                    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para lo que necesitas, te comparto un ejemplo funcional de como puedes hacer lo que necesitas.

Solo debes adaptar las cosas como las deseas. El ejemplo solo funciona cuando seleccionas la primer opcion del primer select, esto para que se cumplieran validaciones y pudieras ver la funcionalidad.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#sel-principal").change(function () {
          var val = $(this).val();

          if (val === "1") {
            var selSecundario = $("#sel-secundario");
            selSecundario.val("4"); // Seteamos el valor del segundo select
            selSecundario.trigger("change"); // Ejecutamos el evento change del select seteado
          }
        });
        $("#sel-secundario").change(function () {
          var val = $(this).val();
          console.log(val);
          var selTerciario = $("#sel-terciario");
          if (val === "4") {
            selTerciario.append([
              $("<option>", { value: "7", text: "Siete" }),
              $("<option>", { value: "8", text: "Ocho" }),
              $("<option>", { value: "9", text: "Nueve" }),
            ]);
          }
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <select name="sel-principal" id="sel-principal">
      <option value="" selected disabled>Seleccione principal</option>
      <option value="1">Uno</option>
      <option value="2">Dos</option>
      <option value="3">Tres</option>
    </select>
    <select name="sel-secundario" id="sel-secundario">
      <option value="" selected disabled>Seleccione Secundario</option>
      <option value="4">Cuatro</option>
      <option value="5">Cinco</option>
      <option value="6">Seis</option>
    </select>
    <select name="sel-terciario" id="sel-terciario">
      <option value="" selected disabled>Seleccione Terciario</option>
    </select>
  </body>
</html>
```

Espero te sirva

Comment: si me sirvio muchas gracias

Comment: @Andrescanizales Vale, me alegro. Podrías marcar la respuesta como aceptada, Muchas gracias